# How to find the lowest number in an array

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

[image: sample dataframe]

This is the data frame. I'm trying to get the lowest number in the key column and create an additional column showing the lowest value. I was trying this but it isn't working.

```scala
def minUdf = udf((arr: dat1[String])=> {
  val filtered = arr.filterNot(_ == "")
  if(filtered.isEmpty) 0
  else filtered.map(_.toInt).min
})
dat1.select(col("placekey"), minUdf(col("key")).as("lowest_value").show(false)
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. A few remarks, your tags mention pyspark but your code isn't python, probably best to use `apache-spark` tag instead. Also instead of adding a screenshot you'll often get better/quicker answers if you add sample data which people can copy/paste. Then given that sample data provide your expected result.

Comment: Can you put an example of what is expected and how key column is supposed to be an array

Comment: `F.regexp_extract("key", r"(\d+)", 1)` - it doesn't look like you truly need a udf for this.